Open existing Page as a Modal
I have the case that I can only edit/add CSS and Javascript. I have an existing link with an a tag inside a classed span. If I click on the a tag, I want to open the link as a modal.
Remember, I cannot change HTML or other attributes. I am fairly new to this thing so I came here to ask.
<span class="spanclass">
  <a href="thisismylink">MyLinkTargetText</a>
</span>

I want the a href to open the same page as a modal.
Is there a solution to this?
I tried various snippets from the internet, but none seemed to work they way I want them to. Help!

You need to add a new JS library which can open modal windows and reference that in your HTML - which may not be possible depending on how strict your 'no HTML changes' restriction is. Assuming you are able to add that library, then it should just be a couple of lines of JS to attach it to the a element.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
